# BooleanBinding de múltiplas propriedades

Tags: java, javafx, binding

Fiz a seguinte estrutura para quando tornar um dos componentes invisível, os outros seguirem a mesma configuração.

```
A.visibleProperty().bindBidirectional(B.visibleProperty()); 
A.visibleProperty().bindBidirectional(C.visibleProperty());
A.visibleProperty().bindBidirectional(D.visibleProperty());`
```

Funciona perfeitamente, porém, gostaria de encontrar uma maneira de fazer isso mais diretamente, exemplo:

```
A.bindBidirectional(B.bindBidirectional(C));
```

algo nesse sentido. Se alguém souber como ajudar, por favor responda. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não há nenhuma maneira de fazer isso já que o objeto tem varias propriedades que podem ser ligadas, por isso A.bindBidirectional(B.bindBidirectional(C)) a classe não saberia qual atributo ele deve fazer a ligação.
Mas para facilitar seu trabalho você pode fazer uma classe que faze ligação de dados.

```
public class BindUtil{
    public static void bindVisibleProperty(Node a, Node b){
        A.visibleProperty().bindBidirectional(B.visibleProperty()); 
    }

    ///... métodos que fazem  bind com outras propriedades
}
```

Então apenas faça isso.

```
BindUtil.bindVisibleProperty(a, b);
```